# Time Machine Hangs (After "Preparing" - 280Gb of 797Gb)

Tags: time-machine, macos, performance

Thanks for reading this. Here's the details:

1. I have done a complete wipe of the HD and clean install of Sierra.
2. I only restored my data files from a non-Time Machine backup.
3. I have only installed apps from fresh downloads or original CD/DVDs.
4. The machine is a 2011 iMac 27" with 16 Gb and 1 TB HD.
5. Parallels is installed and it's running fine for the one app I need to use.
6. The TM backup fails at around 280GB every time.
7. I took the original TM drive (WD 1TB), reformatted it, connected it to my MBA and Time Machine ran perfectly.
8. I took another WD 1TB drive, reformatted it, connected it to the iMac and started a new TM backup. It hangs right at that 280GB point.
9. Via Terminal I ran the following command: 
    log show --predicate 'subsystem == "com.apple.TimeMachine"' --info 
   10.I received the following information:

> System mode = INFO STREAM_LIVE
>
> My-iMac:~ MyUser$ log show --predicate 'subsystem ==
>   "com.apple.TimeMachine"' --info
>
> Skipping debug messages, pass --debug to include.
>
> Filtering the log data using "subsystem == "com.apple.TimeMachine""
>
> Timestamp                       Thread     Type        Activity
>   PID     2016-10-15 19:37:08.967554-0400 0x360684   Info        0x0
>   177    backupd-helper: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogInfo]
>   Not starting scheduled Time Machine backup: No destinations resolvable
>
> 2016-10-15 19:37:39.705181-0400 0x36095e   Info        0x0
>   177    backupd-helper: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogInfo]
>   Not starting scheduled Time Machine backup: No destinations resolvable
>
> 2016-10-15 21:35:35.680687-0400 0x3dd546   Info        0x0
>   177    backupd-helper: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogInfo]
>   Not starting scheduled Time Machine backup: No destinations resolvable
>
> 2016-10-15 21:36:05.899859-0400 0x3dd546   Info        0x0
>   177    backupd-helper: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogInfo]
>   Not starting scheduled Time Machine backup: No destinations resolvable
>
> 2016-10-16 08:24:09.935838-0400 0x4ac59c   Error       0x0
>   34     UserEventAgent: (TimeMachine)
>   [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogError] Failed to send message because the
>   port couldn't be created.
>
> 2016-10-16 08:24:19.617684-0400 0x137a     Error       0x0
>   320    UserEventAgent: (TimeMachine)
>   [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogError] com.apple.TMHelperAgent.SetupOffer
>   enabled
>
> 2016-10-16 08:24:19.979558-0400 0x4ad101   Error       0x0
>   34     UserEventAgent: (TimeMachine)
>   [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogError] Failed to send message because the
>   port couldn't be created.
>
> 2016-10-16 09:24:29.803739-0400 0x4ae304   Info        0x0
>   14398  backupd: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogInfo] Copied
>   27.09 GB of 724.83 GB, 480886 of 1033178 items
>
> 2016-10-16 10:24:33.049795-0400 0x4ae304   Info        0x0
>   14398  backupd: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogInfo] Copied
>   61.18 GB of 724.83 GB, 481194 of 1033178 items
>
> 2016-10-16 11:24:33.206805-0400 0x4ae304   Info        0x0
>   14398  backupd: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogInfo] Copied
>   73.51 GB of 724.83 GB, 491163 of 1033178 items
>
> 2016-10-16 12:24:38.632620-0400 0x4ae304   Info        0x0
>   14398  backupd: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogInfo] Copied
>   100.34 GB of 724.83 GB, 493153 of 1033178 items
>
> 2016-10-16 13:24:43.724930-0400 0x4ae304   Info        0x0
>   14398  backupd: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogInfo] Copied
>   145.64 GB of 724.83 GB, 493153 of 1033178 items
>
> 2016-10-16 14:24:45.201269-0400 0x4ae304   Info        0x0
>   14398  backupd: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogInfo] Copied
>   182.62 GB of 724.83 GB, 508541 of 1033178 items
>
> 2016-10-16 14:35:22.995746-0400 0x5e59df   Info        0x0
>   177    backupd-helper: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogInfo]
>   Not starting scheduled Time Machine backup: Backup already running
>
> 2016-10-16 14:35:22.997422-0400 0x5e59df   Info        0x0
>   177    backupd-helper: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogInfo]
>   Not starting scheduled Time Machine backup: Backup already running
>
> 2016-10-16 15:24:46.087902-0400 0x4ae304   Info        0x0
>   14398  backupd: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogInfo] Copied
>   235.82 GB of 724.83 GB, 524663 of 1033178 items
>
> 2016-10-16 16:24:46.990215-0400 0x4ae304   Info        0x0
>   14398  backupd: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogInfo] Copied
>   270.76 GB of 724.83 GB, 639417 of 1033178 items
>
> 2016-10-16 16:55:29.860342-0400 0x5f3c8d   Info        0x0
>   177    backupd-helper: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogInfo]
>   Not starting scheduled Time Machine backup: Backup already running
>
> 2016-10-16 16:55:30.031563-0400 0x5f3c8d   Info        0x0
>   177    backupd-helper: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogInfo]
>   Not starting scheduled Time Machine backup: Backup already running
>
> 2016-10-16 17:55:29.176625-0400 0x62fca7   Info        0x0
>   177    backupd-helper: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogInfo]
>   Not starting scheduled Time Machine backup: Backup already running
>
> 2016-10-16 18:50:52.402975-0400 0x634fd2   Info        0x0
>   177    backupd-helper: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogInfo]
>   Not starting scheduled Time Machine backup: Backup already running
>
> 2016-10-16 21:13:49.493853-0400 0x642ad1   Info        0x0
>   177    backupd-helper: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogInfo]
>   Not starting scheduled Time Machine backup: Backup already running
>
> 2016-10-16 21:13:49.541508-0400 0x642ad1   Info        0x0
>   177    backupd-helper: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine.TMLogInfo]
>   Not starting scheduled Time Machine backup: Backup already running
>
> ---
>
> Log      - Default:          0, Info:               20, Debug:
>   0, Error:          3, Fault:          0 Activity - Create:
>   0, Transition:          0, Actions:           0

And there we have it. Still hung... Still hanging... Your assistance and suggestions are appreciated.

EDIT: If I cancel out and restart it will backup another 2-3GB and then hang again.